# Why can you assign Nothing to an Integer in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Why am I allowed to assign `Nothing` to a value-type in VB.NET:

```
Dim x as Integer = Nothing
```

But I'm not allowed to assign `null` in C#:

```
int x = null;
```

Comment: Why is it that you can split an infinitive in English but not in Latin?  Because English and Latin are different languages with different rules. C# and VB are similar -- as are Latin and English -- but the rules of one are not the rules of the other.

Comment: So you mean VB is a dead language Eric? :)

Comment: setting `x = Nothing` is confusing, because is not clear at first view that is equivalent to `x = 0`. When `Nothing` is expected to be a invalid value and `0` - a valid one this assignment can bring bugs implicit bugs and misunderstandings in the VB.NET code.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When you assign `Nothing` to a value type in VB.Net it instantiates that type with its default value. So in this case you're not creating a null integer, but an integer that holds the default value of 0

Comment: So it's like:  x = default(int) in C# ?

Comment: From the VB.NET Language Reference: "Assigning Nothing to a variable sets it to the default value for its declared type. If that type contains variable members, they are all set to their default values" ... "If the variable is of a reference type — that is, an object variable — Nothing means the variable is not associated with any object."

Comment: @JoelFan
You nailed it, the c# equivalent of vb's "i = Nothing" is "i = default(Int32)".  Any value type (is defined as a struct opposed to a class) will get the appropriate default value and any reference type will become null.

Comment: @Eric, so in the general case, it would be like: x = default(x.GetType())

Comment: @JoelFan In spirit, but it's a compile-time thing, so you can't use a run-time method like GetType.  That's why you're always seeing people using exmaples like defualt(String).

Comment: In the latest version of C# you can just use the keyword `default` without specifying a type.... e.g. `int x = default;` which makes it very similar to the VB.Net code `Dim x as Integer = Nothing`

Answer (score 8):

The equivalent C# code looks like this:

```
int x;
x = default(int);
```

Note that for reference types, the same still holds:

```
Dim y As Object
y = Nothing
```

That VB.Net code would look like this if mapped directly to C#:

```
object y;
y = default(object);
```

It's just a nice thing that the default for `object` (or any other reference type) in .Net is `null`.  So we see that VB.Net's `Nothing` is not a direct analog to C#'s `null`, at least when used with value types.

Comment: Not sure about mapping, because VB.NET code has explicit type indication: `Int`. However, code like `Dim X = Nothing` is what you wrote underneath.

Answer (score 6):

An interesting example from the language spec: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=01eee123-f68c-4227-9274-97a13d7cb433&displaylang=en

7.1.1 Nullable Value Types
For value types, a ? modifier can be added to a type name to represent the nullable version of that type. A nullable value type can contain the same values as the non-nullable version of the type as well as the null value. Thus, for a nullable value type, assigning Nothing to a variable of the type sets the value of the variable to the null value, not the zero value of the value type. For example:

```
Dim x As Integer = Nothing
Dim y As Integer? = Nothing

' Prints zero
Console.WriteLine(x)
' Prints nothing (because the value of y is the null value)
Console.WriteLine(y)
```

Answer (score 3):

About `Nothing` from the VB.NET specifications (v.10):

> *Nothing* is a special literal; it does not have a type and is
>   convertible to all types in the type
>   system, including type parameters.
>   When converted to a particular type,
>   it is the equivalent of the default
>   value of that type.

from C# specs (v4)

> The *null*-literal can be implicitly
>   converted to a reference type or
>   nullable type.

So, C# *null* can't be implicitly converted to value types, but VB.NET *Nothing* can.

However setting `x = Nothing` is confusing, because is not clear at first view that is equivalent to `x = 0`.

Especially when `Nothing` is expected to be a invalid value and `0` - a valid one, this assignment can bring misunderstandings or even implicit bugs in the VB.NET code.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an interesting article](http://www.devblog.com/2007/11/nothing-and-null-in-vbnet.html) about VB.NET and Nothing vs. Null. A small excerpt:

---

...value types, can’t be compared to Nothing or Null. Value types are types such as Integers and Bytes. From the Visual Basic Language Reference:

> A value type cannot
>   hold a value of Nothing and reverts to
>   its default value if you assign
>   Nothing to it. If you supply a value
>   type in Expression, IsNothing always
>   returns False.

Comment: I know that, but that is not the question I'm asking... neither example in my question (C# or VB.NET) is using nullable types

Comment: comparisons like `If myInt = Nothing Then` are allowed in VB.NET