# How to delete values from array in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have an array that contains these values

`{1, 5, 16, 15}`

I want to delete the first element so that the values are now.

`{Null, 5, 16, 15}`

I then want to go through again and delete the first non-null value, which would yield:

`{Null, Null, 16, 15}`

How do I code this in VB?

Comment: What is the type of the elements of `myArray`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To UBound(myArray)
    If Not IsNothing(myArray(i)) Then
        myArray(i) = Nothing
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

as @Andrew Morton mentioned, a normal Integer value cannot be Null (Nothing).  There is a nullable integer type `Integer?` which can be set to a Null value (Nothing in this case).  The above code would only be appropriate if the array was of `Integer?` values rather than an `Integer` value.

Comment: Did you test that code? Did you notice that the elements you set to `Nothing` came out as zero instead of `Nothing`?

Comment: I was not able to test that code.  I assumed he was using an `Integer?` if he wanted to set them to Null.  I should have clarified, my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

An Integer in VB.NET is a *value type*. If you try to set it to `Nothing` (there is no `null` in VB.NET) then it takes its default value, which for an Integer is zero.

You can use a `Nullable(Of Integer)` instead, which can also be written as `Integer?`.

As a demonstration:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim myArray As Integer?() = {1, 5, 16, 15}

        For j = 1 To 3

            For i = 0 To UBound(myArray)
                If myArray(i).HasValue Then
                    myArray(i) = Nothing
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i

            ' show the values...
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", myArray.Select(Function(n) If(n.HasValue, n.Value.ToString(), "Nothing"))))

        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> Nothing, 5, 16, 15
>   Nothing, Nothing, 16, 15
>   Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 15

If you are interested in the difference from C# see, e.g., [Why can you assign Nothing to an Integer in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776902/why-can-you-assign-nothing-to-an-integer-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim strArray() As Integer = {1, 5, 16, 15}
Dim strValues = strArray().ToList
Dim index = 3
strValues = strValues.Where(Function(s) s <> strValues(index)).ToArray
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
Dim myArray(3) As Integer
    myArray(0) = 1
    myArray(1) = 2
    myArray(2) = 3
    myArray(3) = 4
myArray = removeVal(myArray, 2)
```

-

```
Function removeVal(ByRef Array() As Integer, ByRef remove As Integer) As Integer()
    Array(remove) = Nothing
    Return Array
End Function
```